# Calculating Upper and Lower Sums for the Function f(x) = cos²(πx)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Given the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=cos^{2}(\pi x)$
and the partition $P=\left\{ \frac{k}{n}\mid k=0,1,\ldots,2n\right\}$.

How can I calculate the upper sum U(f,P) of the function f(x) over the given partition P?

Similarly, how can I calculate the lower sum L(f,P) of the function f(x) over the partition P?

How to determine whether the sum, S, of the function f(x) over the partition P is an upper sum or a lower sum.

Any insights or step-by-step explanations on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please, include your efforts. You can clearly make a huge progress just by using the definition of the sums you want to calculate

Comment: I appreciate your guidance. However, I'm facing some challenges in using the definitions to calculate the upper and lower sums for the function. The main difficulty arises from the fact that 'n' is not constant, making it challenging to determine if each segment is upper or lower.

Comment: I understand that you're facing some challenges. I don't claim the problem is trivial. But please edit the post and include everything you've tried to solve the problem. This is a general rule in MathSE community